# Fix Static Method issue

Tags: java, static, instance

So I'm relatively new to Java, but I'm having an issue with static content. One I'm not exactly sure what static stuff is, but I know it's ridiculously annoying, secondly, I have this small game of "Pong" I've been working on as an exercise, and I'm trying to get a Scoreboard up but it is saying that `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getScore()`

Here is my code below, any suggestions on it would helpful since I'm still a rookie.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PongGame extends JComponent implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener{
    private int ballX = 385;
    private int ballY = 285;
    private int paddleOpX = 0;
    private int paddleX = 0; 
    private int ballYSpeed = 1;
    private int ballXSpeed = 1;
    public Integer score = 0;

    private static Timer t = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JLabel scoreBoard = new JLabel(getScore().toString());
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Hit the Damn Ball");
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));

        PongGame game = new PongGame();

        window.add(game);

        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        t = new Timer(5, game);
        t.start();

        window.addMouseMotionListener(game);

    }

    //set the size of window
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(110, 65, 13));
        g.fillRect(paddleX, 510, 150, 15);

        g.setColor(new Color(90, 0,0));
        g.fillRect(paddleOpX, 90, 150, 15);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 30, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        paddleOpX = (ballX+5);
        ballX +=ballXSpeed;
        ballY +=ballYSpeed;

        if(ballX >= paddleX-30 && ballX <= (paddleX + 150) && ballY >= 480){
            ballYSpeed = -ballYSpeed;
            //ballYSpeed = -1;
            setScore();
        }
        if(ballX >= paddleX-30 && ballX <= (paddleX + 150) && ballY > 480){
            ballYSpeed = -ballYSpeed;
            //ballYSpeed = 1;
            setScore();
        }
        if(ballX >= paddleOpX-30 && ballX <=(paddleOpX + 150) && ballY <= 106){
            ballYSpeed = ballYSpeed*-1;
        }

        if(ballY > 570){
            ballXSpeed  = 0;
            ballYSpeed = 0;
            t.stop();
            System.out.println(score);
        }
        if(ballX >= 770){
            ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
            //ballXSpeed = -1;
        }
        if(ballY <= 0){
            ballXSpeed  = 0;
            ballYSpeed = 0;
            t.stop();
            System.out.println(score);
            //ballYSpeed = 1;

        }
        if(ballX <= 0){
            ballXSpeed = ballXSpeed*-1;
            //ballXSpeed = 1;
        }
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        paddleX  = e.getX()-75;

        if(ballX >= paddleX-30 && ballX <= (paddleX + 150) && ballY == 480 ){
            ballYSpeed = ballYSpeed-1;
            ballXSpeed = ballXSpeed < 0 ? -2 : 2;
            //ballYSpeed = 1;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    private void setScore(){
        score++;
    }
    public Integer getScore(){
        return score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance method `getScore()` needs an object on which to call the method because it's not `static`, but you don't have one yet.

Move `PongGame game = new PongGame();` to the first line of `main`, then change

```
JLabel scoreBoard = new JLabel(getScore().toString());
```

to

```
JLabel scoreBoard = new JLabel(game.getScore().toString());
```

Comment: okay I did that and it works but now the label won't show up on the screen

Comment: You'll need to `add` the `JLabel` to the `JFrame`'s content pane.

Comment: awesome I think it's just a text color issue now THANK YOU

Comment: actually it is not showing, I placed it after the window.add(game) line but the only thing that showed was the label and nothing else

Comment: I'm not an expert in Swing, but maybe the label needs to be added your game component which needs to be added to the content pane.

Answer (score 0):

`private void setScore()` method is not `static` method and your are trying to call this method from static method, **you have to either make this method as static or call this method using object.**

To create `static` method you have to use `static` modifier in method syntax.

```
private static void setScore(){
        score++;
    }
```

OR

you have to create instance of `PongGame` class and then call that method.

```
PongGame pg = new PongGame();
JLabel scoreBoard = new JLabel(pg.getScore().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

getScore() needs it to be static because you did not put "new", so without an instance of it, it cannot compute.

```
 JLabel scoreBoard = new JLabel(getScore().toString());
```

needs it and you have not declared it as "static".

Static means it is loaded to memory only once and for all
(which is good for some situations (like a web method running on your server(probably has low memory))).

Simple solution:  create an instance and use it.

```
  getScore gs= new getScore()
```

or make it static and use it as

```
  getScore.TosTring();
```

You need to instantiate the superclass before this.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getScore()` is not `static` (because you are not declaring it as `static`), so it needs an instance to be called. In other words, you have to create an instance of your class `PongGame`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    PongGame game = PongGame(...);
    ...
}
```

and then use it to invoke the method:

```
game.getScore();
```

**Note:** A `static` method exists only once per class, so you don't need an instance of the class to call it. In the other hand, a non-`static` method need an instance to be called.